# Reading text file using stream - Variable in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I would like to read a text file, work with the string I have from each line, add a variable and continue.
For example: I have a text file with three lines and I'd like to add a variable to the end of each line which gets upped by one for each line.

To break everything down I made an example program but I still do not get fully behind it.

My text file "test.txt" has three lines of text "Line1", "Line2" and "Line3" and I have an Integer named testNum with a value of 500 which I would like to up after each line.

My code is the following:

```
String fileName = "test.txt";
int testNum = 1024;

Stream<String> readFileStream = null;
try {
    readFileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
readFileStream.forEach( line -> {            
    System.out.println(line+testNum);
    testNum++;
});
```

Now I understand that the issue lies in the lambda expression. Can someone explain to me why I need local variables for the lambda expression and am unable to access variables declared outside from it?

Moreover, I tried to change my code to use a for each instead but for each seems not applicable for "Stream", e.g.:

```
for(String line : readFileStream){
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: it is explained here..
http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-are-the-reasons-for-the-restriction-to-effective-immutability/

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the time and place of creation of a lambda expression differs from the time and place of execution. Sometimes, a lambda expression is created in method A and executed in method B half minutes or hours later. And it might be executed on a different thread. So it would not be sensible to write to variables with method scope (i.e. stack variables that only exist while the method is executed). Read access to those variable is allowed as their value is 'copied' into the lambda expression at creation time.

In your case, it might be easier to give up streams and use the `List` version of `Files.lines(...)`, so you can iterate via for-loop:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename));
int testNum = 500;
for(String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line + testNum);
    testNum++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use streams for this task you can create a specific String consumer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

```
String fileName = "test.txt";

Stream<String> readFileStream = null;
try {
    readFileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

readFileStream.forEach(
    new Consumer<String>() {
        int testNum = 1024;
        public void accept(String line) {
            try {
                System.out.println(line + testNum++);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```